# Alphabets and Arabic numerals in Sansfont using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, sans-serif

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}%
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Mapping=tex-text,Path = ../fonts/MinionPro/ ,
UprightFont= MinionPro-Regular.otf,
BoldFont= MinionPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont= MinionPro-It.otf,
BoldItalicFont= MinionPro-BoldIt.otf,
]{MinionPro}%
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=bfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=bfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\RequirePackage{MnSymbol}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}%
\begin{document}

This is for test $a+b=c=\int$

\vspace{3pc}

\sffamily

This is for test $a+b=c=\sum$

\end{document}
```

This produced the output as:

[image]

I need to get the alpha characters are in `Sans-italic` font and the arabic numerals are in `Sans-Roman` font, as marked, please advise.

Comment: why xits math, not a sans math font such as fira math?